# Tamanho do nome dos parâmetros influencia no tempo de requisição http?

Tags: c#, web-service, http, request

Uma requisição http para um serviço tem sua performance (consumo de banda/internet/tempo) alterada se o nome dos parâmetros forem grandes?

Exemplo.
Requisição **POST** com os seguintes parâmetros

```
{
"IdUsuario": 30735209,
"IdProdutoBase": 2,
"JsonServico": {
    "IdCliente": 6,
    "Versao": "1.6.0"
  } 
}
```

A requisição ficaria mais rápida se fosse:

```
{
    "ius": 30735209,
    "ipb": 2,
    "jds": {
        "icl": 6,
        "vsa": "1.6.0"
      } 
}
```

Comment: Um tempo totalmente irrisório. E só vai piorar no entendimento do código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim altera a performance, deixando mais lento, aumentando processamento e consumindo mais banda, **mas é nesse caso à um nível irrisório**, como comentou o brhvitor6.

A versão com parâmetros com nomes maiores logicamente será maior, consequentemente leva mais tempo para ser transferida e processada.

Mas como nessa época de apps e conexões 3G, queremos economizar cada bit, por isso encontramos hoje ferramentas que fazem bundle e minification de javascript, por exemplo, para reduzir o tráfego.

Uma coisa boa você já está fazendo, usando JSON ao invés de um XML (que por causa de suas tags abrindo e fechando gastam mais bytes.

Se você for feliz e não complicar seu código com nomes como "ius" ao invés de "IdUsuário", vá em frente, mais saiba que não vai mudar muita coisa e o esforço da mudança pode não valer a pena.

Answer (score 1):

Ative a compactação gzip no seu servidor que terá melhores resultados. Se ainda assim não estiver satisfeito com o tamanho e tempo de parsing, pode experimentar outros formatos, de preferência binários, como o [msgpack](http://msgpack.org/).